# How to do refunds and internal transfers on bitcoind?

Tags: sending

I would like to ask regarding refunds and internal transfers. It wouldn't be difficult if not for the network fee.

How can one do internal transfers without network fees and another is refunds in bitcoind or bitcoindxt?

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no distinction between "external" and "internal" transfers in bitcoin. If you want coins to be in another address, you have to pay the transaction fee. That said, you can create a single transaction that does everything you want and only pay the fee once (though, obviously, that transaction will be relatively big, you should still save some fees because you'll not have as much overhead in terms of tx size)